# Pass array of enums in Groovy annotation

Tags: java, arrays, groovy, annotations

I don't know why but I can't pass array to annotation which is declared as separated variable.

```
@Target([ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE ])
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
@interface SomeCustomAnnotation {

  SomeEnum[] someValue()
}
```

_

```
class SomeDataFactory {

static final SOME_ENUM_ARRAY = [SOME_ENUM_1, SOME_ENUM_2].toArray()

  enum SomeEnum {
   SOME_ENUM_1, SOME_ENUM_2
   }
}
```

_

```
class SomeClass {

   @SomeAnnotation(someValue = [SOME_ENUM_1, SOME_ENUM_2]) //fine
   def someMethod1(){}

   @SomeAnnotation(someValue = SOME_ENUM_ARRAY ) //Groovyc: Expected enum value for attribute someValue in @com.somepackage.SomeAnnotation
   def someMethod2(){}
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I would try adding the  `def` keyword to your `static final SOME_ENUM_ARRAY` and instead of using `toArray()` just cast it to `SomeEnum[]`.
Well, or just don't use def and define it as `SomeEnum[]`, should be effectively the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotations expect **inline** constants. So what you're trying to achieve cannot be done, even if variables are declared static and final..

Given that you're already using a separate class to provide the array, you can replace `SomeAnnotation` with its "provider".

There are many ways to do this, but here is an example using a different enum:

```
enum SomeDataProvider {

    SOME_ENUM_ARRAY_PROVIDER([SOME_ENUM_1, SOME_ENUM_2]);

    private List<SomeAnnotation> array

    SomeDataProvider(def array) {
         this.array = array
    }

    public List<SomeAnnotation> getSomeEnumArray() {
       return array;
    }
}
```

Then change the code declaring the annotation to:

```
@SomeAnnotation(someValue = SOME_ENUM_ARRAY_PROVIDER)
def someMethod2(){}
```

Of course, you would need to change the type expected by `SomeCustomAnnotation`:

```
@interface SomeCustomAnnotation {

  SomeDataProvider[] someValue()
}
```

And the processing to obtain `SomeEnum[]` rather by calling:

```
methodg.getDeclaredAnnotation(SomeAnnotation.class)
       .someValue()
       .getSomeEnumArray();
```

You could also replace the `SomeDataProvider` with an interface and make `SomeAnnotation` take a `java.lang.Class` object.

Comment: IntelliJ is giving this hint too. Is there any workaround for it?

Comment: @KamilW. Workearounds depend on how the annotation is being processed. Are you processing the annotation yourself?

Comment: @KamilW. Added a sort of workaround: it assumes you're processing the annotation yourself.

Comment: Big thanks for explanation, I didn't catch it at first.